# Travis.ci - Build and Deploy based PR and Tags

Tags: travis-ci

I'm trying to create two different actions within travis.ci. The first action is to execute a script on every push on every branch. This is currently working as desired. The second is to trigger a different script only when `git push origin --tags`. In short:

1. Execute script1 always (currently working)
2. Execute script2 when tags are pushed

Here is what I'm trying:

```
language: python
python:
  - 3.7
matrix:
  include:
    - python: 3.7
      sudo: true
install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
script: # Always want this to happen
  - invoke package
branches:
  only:
    - master
    - /^x\/.*/
deploy: # Want this to occur on git push origin --tags
  provider: script
  script: invoke release
  on:
    tags: true
```

The deploy section is not being triggered, and I can find no evidence of the `invoke release` script being invoked.

Update:
It may be due to the way I'm pushing tags..? I'm seeing this log in travis now:

```
Skipping a deployment with the script provider because this is not a tagged commit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it from [this github issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2498#issuecomment-48337712). Changed the deploy section to this:

```
deploy:
  provider: script
  script: invoke release
  on:
    tags: true
    all_branches: true
```

but had to remove the branches section. Deployment script was invoked, nonetheless.